# Как писать в jsx html элементы с автозаполнением, к примеру .name ( нажать enter или tab ) и он выдает див с классом name?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

Хочу увеличить скорость написания элементов в Реакте, делаю много легкой практики и там постоянно нужно выводить html элементы но нету таких команд как в html где используются точки в качестве дива с классом или # для id, не подскажите расширение?

Comment: Если редактор vscode, то там по-умолчанию должен быть emmet. https://medium.com/@eshwaren/enable-emmet-support-for-jsx-in-visual-studio-code-react-f1f5dfe8809c

Comment: @1ockeв  а нет, в Html Работает, но вот в js нет. Магия

Comment: В конфиге есть подобное `"emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true`?

Comment: Попробуйте вставить следующее "emmet.includeLanguages": { "javascript": "javascriptreact" }

Comment: @1ocke спасибо за помощь! Проверил json.setting, первое стояло как false, изменил на true, но ничего не изменилось, затем добавил строку с IncludeLanguage, но тоже не дало эффекта. У меня на самом деле было 0 настроек emmet-a в settinge, теперь их 3, но ничего не изменилось.

Comment: @1ocke в общем есть  1ocke Emmet JSS, но он не очень удобный. Нужно 2 раза нажимать изза постоянных подсказон. Это и удобно и нет. Я вот к примеру поторопился и нажал ентер и потом таб, на что у меня получилось не h1 а h1h1 и он создал <h1h1></h1h1> и теперь он запомнил что такое есть и у меня теперь h1 вообще не высвечивается, а высвечивается подсказка h1h1, на что нужно жать esc и только потом жать tab. Вот бы простое без подсказон чтонибудь

Comment: Вообще vscode из коробки умеет разворачивать сокращения тегов. Пробовали обновить редактор или снести его и заново установить?

Comment: @1ocke чтож придется так сделать... у меня там бардак наверное, спасибо за совет)

Comment: Если что, Webstorm поддерживает такое для Реакта из коробки. Только что проверил.

Comment: @sneas блин, такие простые мысли почему то мне в голову не приходят) Я же просто могу попробывать ws, спасибо!

Comment: @sneas уже сутки на ws и скажу вам что это кайф... столько приятных вещей. Даже расширение vim ни разу не тупило, а div и другие вещи настролько мягко и приятно создаются, а подсказки можно тупо по букве нажимать и только успевать хлестать таб или ентер, он просто буквально слова в рот кладет. Каеф, а темы какие и еще проекты не надо самому создавать, выбираешь react и бац, все готово, а еще и расширения уже встроенны почти все, там стилизацию или снипеты какие для удобства а в остальном идеал, благодарю!

Comment: @TANAQ, рад что угодил :)

Comment: @TANAQ, там есть еще одна штука, Live Templates называется - это новая вершина комфорта разработки. Там уже есть куча предустановленных шаблонов и еще можно свои создавать.

Comment: @sneas побежал тестить))) Благодарю!!!